# Can not access disposed object in CellEditFinished event popup messages of ObjectListView

Tags: objectlistview, objectdisposedexception

When I click on the 'Open Modal Window' button in [Main form], it shows the
[subform] that is built with a data list by using the ObjectListView component.

When I click on the "Age" column to edit it and changed the value in the cell to be a non zero value, then click on the blank of the ObjectListView component(if I press Enter, the exception will not come out), it popup a message. I left this message in front of all the opened windows and wait 10 seconds for the application timeout. At that time, an exception shows:

> Cannot access a disposed object. Object name: 'ObjectListView'.

Here is the code:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    modalForm = new Form2();
    StartTimeOutTimer();
    var result = modalForm.ShowDialog(this);
}

private void ProcessTimeOut()
{
    timer1.Stop();
    seconds = 0;
    List<Form> openForms = Application.OpenForms.Cast<Form>().Where(frm => !string.Equals(frm.Name, "Form1") && !frm.IsDisposed).ToList();
    for (var i = openForms.Count - 1; i >= 0; i--)
    {
        openForms[i].Dispose();
    }
}

private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    seconds++;
    if (seconds == 10)
    {
        ProcessTimeOut();
    }
}
```

the exception come out in this line:

> var result = modalForm.ShowDialog(this);

My reputation is too low to upload more links, so I post the code to OneDrive. 
The sample code and solution is here:

https://1drv.ms/u/s!AmQYEYkCV6gqgw6iPMVFPBKlSx1V

I tried to add the source code of ObjectListView in my solution, and the error occurred in the ***GetHeaderControl*** method in the source code of v2.9.0

Please download my sample code to reproduce the exception. How do I fix this exception? Any suggestion will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I download the code and it seems a bug of objeclistview. I cannot fix it, but I have a workaround to resolve your issue: you can ShowDialog() by asynchronously, like this:

```
 this.BeginInvoke(new Action(() => {
         var myMsgBox = new MyMsgBox("Must be 0");
         myMsgBox.ShowDialog();
      }));
```

Comment: That's really a helpful answer. Thanks a lot!